# Can't add comma before string number

Tags: python

I use `re.sub` for add spaces after every capital letter

```
>>> re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", "WordWordWord")
'Word Word Word'
```

but I don't know how to solve below problems

I have string like this `' 90.5% Voted Creative 90.5% Voted Uplifted 91.5% Voted Energetic'` and I want to add comma before start every number in my string except only first number. so the result will be look like this:

```
' 90.5% Voted Creative ,90.5% Voted Uplifted ,91.5% Voted Energetic'
```

I tried this:

```
>>> finallist = [ ", ".join(item.split(" ")) for item in mylist ]
>>> finallist
[', 90.5%, VotedCreative, 90.5%, VotedUplifted, 91.5%, VotedEnergetic']
```

it's adding comma after every string which I don't want

how to do it in python by using `re.sub` or any better way???

Comment: The first example uses regular expressions (`re`), which allows you to be specific about matching conditions. The second example uses split, which splits for every occurrence of `" "` in your case - why not use a regex for the second example as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) with lookaround:

```
>>> s = ' 90.5% Voted Creative 90.5% Voted Uplifted 91.5% Voted Energetic'
>>> ','.join(re.split('(?<=\S)(?=\s\d)', s))
' 90.5% Voted Creative, 90.5% Voted Uplifted, 91.5% Voted Energetic'
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=...)` - [Lookbehind](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html#index-22)

  - `\S` - Non-whitespace character
- `(?=...)` - [Lookahead](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html#index-20)

  - `\s` - Whitespace character
  - `\d` - Digit

Comment: Thanks wjandrea. It worked. can you please give me the documentation link which I can read for better understanding.

Comment: @ByHala Added to answer

Answer (score 2):

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\S)(?=\s\d)', ',', s)
```

Same idea as wjandrea's answer but works in Python 3.6. `re.split('(?<=\S)(?=\s\d)', s)` does not work in Python 3.6 (at least not in Python 3.6.7): `ValueError: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.`

It works even better with

```
re.sub(r'(?<=[^\s,])(?=\s+\d)', ',', s)
```

`[^,\s]`: wont insert ',' if there is already a ',' in place (`[^\s]` is equivalent to `\S`)

`\s+`: insert ',' in the right place if there are multiple spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my simple approach. To avoid the first comma, you can use `str.strip()` to remove the leading whitespace.

```
text = ' 90.5% Voted Creative 90.5% Voted Uplifted 91.5% Voted Energetic'
print(re.sub(r" ([0-9.]+)", r", \1", text.strip()))
```

Output:

```
'90.5% Voted Creative, 90.5% Voted Uplifted, 91.5% Voted Energetic'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `re.sub` with the `count` parameter:

```py
s = " 90.5% Voted Creative 90.5% Voted Uplifted 91.5% Voted Energetic"

import re

regexp = r'(\d+\.\d+\%)'
result = re.sub(regexp, r',\1', s)
result = re.sub(',' + regexp, r'\1', result, 1)
print(result)
```